# Are Roth IRA dividends taxable?

Tags: united-states, taxes, roth-ira, dividends

Are dividends from a 5+ year old established Roth IRA for a person over 70 1/2 tax free? I understand withdrawals of principal are tax free as they have already been taxed.

Comment: FWIW OP, when people mention that IRAs are 'tax-advantaged', this is what they're talking about. Other investment accounts do get taxed on the dividends.

Answer (score 23):

For a Roth IRA, everything withdrawn is tax free as long as you meet the age/time requirements.

You are correct that the contributions have been taxed; but the dividends, interest, and growth due to the price of the underlying securities are also tax free.

Also note - the key age is 59-1/2 for this to be true. 70-1/2 is when RMDs (required minimum distributions) take effect **but there are no RMDs for Roth IRAs;** you don't need to take any money out of a Roth IRA if you don't want to, and when you do take a distribution, it is 
(Federal) tax-free (subject, of course, to the 5-year and 59-1/2 years
requirements.

Comment: Dilip - thanks for catching my bad edit. Inherited Roths do have RMDs, but not regular Roths. OP's use of 70-1/2 implied to me some misunderstanding somewhere.